# Implement sticky footer for acquia_marina

Tags: 7, theming

I've searched for a Drupal-friendly sticky footer solution for the Acquia Marina theme for Drupal 7, but I couldn't find anything.

2 examples are given here for Drupal 6: http://drupal.org/node/554048. The first solution is JavaScript-based and the second is CSS-based.

Will the CSS/JS examples given work for Drupal 7? If not, can anyone suggest a simple solution to get the footer to stick to the bottom of the browser window?

My site is running drupal-7.10, fusion-7.x-1.x-dev and acquia_marina-7.x-1.x-dev.

Comment: Does your footer has a fixed height ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CSS solution](http://drupal.org/node/554048#comment-3270682) should be implemented the same way in Drupal 7.

Here is the javascript code updated to Drupal 7.

```js
(function ($) {
Drupal.behaviors.acquia_marinaStickyFooter = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    var footer_height = $('#footer').height();
    var footer_pos = $('#footer').position();
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var page_height = $('#page').height();
    var page_pos = $('#page').position();
    var page_total = page_pos.top + page_height;
    var footer_new_pos = window_height - footer_height - page_total;
    var test = footer_height + page_total;
    if (test <= window_height) {
      if (footer_pos.top < window_height) {
        $('#footer').css('position', 'relative');
        $('#footer').css('margin-top', footer_new_pos);
      }
    }
  }
};
})(jQuery);
```